# Excel VBA send email when cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

This code will send email to me that refers to cell O30 and Q30 when cell R30 have changes. I also want apply this code when R31 changes, it will send email that refer for cell O31 and Q31 and loop for the rest. Can anybody help me through this..?

Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R30")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim OutlookApp As Object
        Dim OutlookEmail As Object

        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With OutlookEmail
            .To = "xxx@yahoo.com" 'Replace with the email address of the recipient
            .Subject = "Excel cell R30 has been changed"
            .Body = "The value of cell R30 is now " & Range("R30").Value & ". The values of cells O30 and Q30 are " & Range("O30").Value & " and " & Range("Q30").Value & " respectively."
            .Send
        End With

        Set OutlookEmail = Nothing
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Already try to modified but it not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the range from the target to `Range("R30:R31")` or include as many rows as you would like.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookEmail As Object
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim strSubj As String

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
        
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R30:R31")) Is Nothing Then

        strBody = "The value of cell R" & Target.Row & " is now " & Range("R" & Target.Row).Value & ". The values of cells O" & Target.Row & " and Q" & Target.Row & " are " & Range("O" & Target.Row).Value & " and " & Range("Q" & Target.Row).Value
        strSubj = "Excel cell R" & Target.Row & " has been changed"
        With OutlookEmail
            .To = "xxx@yahoo.com" 'Replace with the email address of the recipient
            .Subject = strSubj
            .Body = strBody & " respectively."
            .Send
        End With
    End If
    
    Set OutlookEmail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Tony.. ITS WORKKKKK!!! Tq so MUCHHHHHHH!!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem though you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the help of offset()
This would work for R30:R33, change as required.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R30:R33")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim OutlookApp As Object
        Dim OutlookEmail As Object
        Dim r       As String
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        r = Target.Row
        With OutlookEmail
            .To = "xxx@yahoo.com"        'Replace with the email address of the recipient
            .Subject = "Excel cell R" & r & " has been changed"
            .Body = "The value of cell R" & r & " Is now " & Target.Value & ". The values of cells O" & r & " And Q" & r & " are " & Target.Offset(, -3).Value & " And " & Target.Offset(, -1) & " respectively."
            .display        '.Send
        End With
        
        Set OutlookEmail = Nothing
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```